# jQuery value change event delay

Tags: jquery

I want to execute a function like 2 seconds after a user has finished typing in the textbox. If they continue to type after 1 second, the delay time is reset back to 2.

It should function something similar to an autocomplete box.

I know of 2 events: `change` and `keyup`. The problem I have with `change` is that the textbox has to loose focus for it to be triggered. for `keyup`, what if they use the mouse to paste a text?

Could I be helped here?

Answer (score 31):

There's the HTML5 `oninput` event, supported by all the current major browsers and can be worked into IE 8 and lower:

```
$("#myInput").bind("input", function () {
    // ...
})
```

- http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/09/effectively-detecting-user-input-in-javascript (explanation)
- http://whattheheadsaid.com/projects/input-special-event (plugin)

---

A very simple cross browser approach would be

```
$("#myInput").bind("input propertychange", function (evt) {
    // If it's the propertychange event, make sure it's the value that changed.
    if (window.event && event.type == "propertychange" && event.propertyName != "value")
        return;

    // Clear any previously set timer before setting a fresh one
    window.clearTimeout($(this).data("timeout"));
    $(this).data("timeout", setTimeout(function () {
        // Do your thing here
    }, 2000));
});
```

This would make the event fire twice in IE 9 (one for `propertychange`, one for `input`), but it doesn't matter because of the nature of the event handler.

Comment: Should event.type be evt.type in your example? Looks good, i think i [may borrow this. IE7 fires multiple propertychanges, even onblur. Does that this catch them and only handle it once? Also is the purpose of the timer?

Comment: @armyofda12mnkeys: nope, `event.type` is correct, it's looking for the global `event` object supplied in IE. You could change it to `window.event.*` if you want to be more cautious. It only handles changes to the `value` property, if it fires more than once then it cancels the timer set by the previous.

Answer (score 13):

You can bind the `input` event and also `keyup` for fallback on older browsers. You can then start a timer, which gets reset every time a user action is detected. By saving the timer handle in the current element's data makes sure multiple elements don't interfere with each other.

```
$('input').bind('input keyup', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var delay = 2000; // 2 seconds delay after last input

    clearTimeout($this.data('timer'));
    $this.data('timer', setTimeout(function(){
        $this.removeData('timer');

        // Do your stuff after 2 seconds of last user input
    }, delay));
});
```

Comment: `propertychange` is a better choice over `keyup`.  It's supported by Internet Explorer and will fire whenever the user does something to change the `value` property of the input field, making it just as good as `input`.  See my answer above.

Comment: `select` has `change` for this purpose

Answer (score 2):

You can put on both change and keyup:

```
var globalTimeout;

$(function() {
    $("#myInput").change(initTimer).keyup(initTimer);
});

function initTimer() {
    if (globalTimeout) clearTimeout(globalTimeout);
    globalTimeout = setTimeout(handler, 2000);
}

function handler() {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`keyup` will work:

```
$("#s").keyup(function(e){
    $("#t").html($(this).val());
});
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3nx6t/

Comment: `keyup` is a poor event for detecting user input.  It only fires when the user lifts his finger off the key and it only fires for keyboard input (no paste, drag/drop, spell checker corrections, etc).

Comment: @Andy: Please see the demo. jQuery 1.6 support pasting too!

Comment: @kingjiv and @Andy, my mistake, yes it won't work with mouse interactions, however if we bind the `input` event, we can do so, like @Andy did.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
$("selector").keyup(function(){
   if(typeof(window.delayer) != 'undefined')
      clearTimeout(window.delayer);
   window.delayer = setTimeout(function_you_want_to_get_execute_with_delay, 2000);
});
```

Cheers